# Why does LocationManager calls startUpdatingLocation multiple times?

Tags: swift, location, locationmanager

Why is the Location Manager calling `startUpdatingLocation` more than once? Sometimes it is calling once, other times it is calling it three times. I don't know why; maybe you could help me. I have this code from GitHub.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate
{

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in

            if (error != nil)
            {
                print("Error: " + error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if placemarks!.count > 0 {
                if let pm = placemarks?.first {
                    self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                print("Error with the data.")
            }
        })
    }

    func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark)
    {

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        print(placemark.locality)
        print(placemark.postalCode)
        print(placemark.administrativeArea)
        print(placemark.country)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
    {
        print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

Comment: But you are asking why didUpdateLocations is called multiple times, aren't you ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is standard behavior. When you start location services you will generally receive a series of increasingly accurate `CLLocation` updates (i.e. with `horizontalAccuracy` decreasing over time) as the device "warms up". For example, it might start reporting location information that it might already have on the basis of cell towers, but as the GPS chip gets more information by which it can better triangulate your location, it will give you updates. Etc.

If you want to reduce this behavior, you can use a combination of a larger `distanceFilter`, a lower `desiredAccuracy`, or call `stopUpdatingLocation` once you get a location that you will geocode.

Right now you are calling `stopUpdatingLocation`, but you're doing it from the asynchronously called closure of `reverseGeocodeLocation`. This means that more location updates are able to slip in before the completion handler of `reverseGeocodeLocation` is called. If you call  `stopUpdatingLocation` synchronously (e.g. before `reverseGeocodeLocation`), then you will avoid this behavior.

Comment: Have you an example code for me? Like you see I am using stopUpdatingLocation but it don't work like I want it.

Comment: You're stopping it in a method that you're calling from the asynchronously executed closure of `reverseGeocodeLocation`. So, by the time that closure is called, a few more location updates may have come in. Bottom line, don't stop it asynchronously, but rather do so synchronously (e.g. before you call `reverseGeocodeLocation`).