# Why is my CLLocationManager sometimes updating location twice after startUpdatingLocation is called

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

Once a button is pressed, I have a CLLocationManager that requests authorization for location services and if the user accepts, the locationManager will call startUpdatingLocation().  Once there is an updated location (which is immediately), I expect the ClLocationManagerDelegate to call didUpdateLocations and from there I immediately call manager.stopUpdatingLocation() so that I ONLY get 1 set of coordinates for the time being.  However, sometimes (inconsistently) I will get two sets of coordinates as if the button was pressed twice in succession.  I understand startUpdatingLocation can be tricky because it can very rapidly update your location until it is stopped but I can't seem to pinpoint where and how to avoid this!  I found many threads on this same issue but nothing that has worked for my specific case.

I looked online and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051873/why-does-locationmanager-calls-startupdatinglocation-multiple-times) and tried a couple of the things in that thread but still could not fix it.

Below is my code:

**getUserLocation()** is the first function called when the button in my app is pressed.

```
func getUserLocation() {
    self.places.removeAll()
    self.placesTableView.reloadData()

    LocationService.shared.requestPermissionToAccessLocation()
    LocationService.shared.locationUpdated = { [weak self] location in
        self?.fetchPlaces(location: location)
    }

    self.view.addSubview(placesTableView)
    placesTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
        [
            placesTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 200),
            placesTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 150),
            placesTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            placesTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -130),
        ]
    )
}

private func fetchPlaces(location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let searchSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
    let searchRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: searchSpan)

    let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request()
    searchRequest.region = searchRegion
    searchRequest.resultTypes = .pointOfInterest
    searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = "bar"

    let search = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)

    search.start { response, error in
        guard let mapItems = response?.mapItems else {
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            for item: MKMapItem in mapItems {
                let placeMark = item.placemark as CLPlacemark

                let completeBusinessString = String(format: "%@\n%@ %@\n%@, %@ %@", placeMark.name!, placeMark.subThoroughfare!, placeMark.thoroughfare!, placeMark.locality!, placeMark.administrativeArea!, placeMark.postalCode!)

                self?.places.append(completeBusinessString)
            }
            self?.placesTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

**LocationServices singleton class**

```
class LocationService: NSObject {

    static let shared = LocationService()

    lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
        let manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.delegate = self
        return manager
    }()

    var locationUpdated: ((CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Void)?

    override private init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func requestPermissionToAccessLocation() {
        switch locationManager.authorizationStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .denied:
            break
        case .authorizedAlways:
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        default:
            break
        }
    }

}

extension LocationService: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        if let location = locations.last?.coordinate {
            print(location)
            locationUpdated?(location)
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        switch manager.authorizationStatus {
        case .authorizedAlways:
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        default:
            break
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should look at the location accuracy and use the value with the best accuracy.

Comment: @HangarRash why? I am using kCLLocationAccuracyBest. Why would the accuracy of my location have anything to do with startUpdatingLocation() and it randomly reporting back more than one set of coordinates in one button press?

Comment: look into `async/await`/Concurrency. You can convert the location service code into compatible code and eliminate races.

Comment: @BiggRojo Because it’s not uncommon to get location values with undesired accuracy. Simply ignore undesired values and your issue will likely be solved.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to get just one value that tells you the location, you're making the wrong call; use [`requestLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620548-requestlocation).

Comment: I tried this already. I replaced all the spots where i call startUpdatingLocation with requestionLocation and it will still sometimes give me two coordinates.  It's pretty inconsistent and it appears I have some kind of race condition going on in my code that i can't seem to find @matt

Comment: Well you haven't shown enough for _me_ to be able to spot it. You'll have to debug. But personally I would suggest that you just debounce so that if two values come in within a very short time of one another, you just ignore one of them. Pretty simple to do (though, to be sure, it would be nice to track down the issue).